# pulling an older version of a git repo to xcode

Tags: xcode, git

I am trying to get started editing an ios app that is stored on a bitbucket repo. The most recent version of the app crashes with a message:

```
[Crashlytics] Version 3.3.4 (82) 
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value 
(lldb)
```

So, I am trying to pull an older version of the app.

I click "Check out an existing project" Then it prompts for me to enter the location of repository. I have no problem pulling and running the most recent version from the repo. Is there some way to specify that I do not want it to use the most recent version?

**EDIT 1**

The window I am working with looks almost exactly like this: http://www.techotopia.com/images/6/68/Xcode_6_add_git_repository_dialog.png

Comment: You need `git checkout <some_idenfifier>` where `<some_identifier>` is a commit SHA1 or a tag.  You do this from the top-level Xcode project folder.  I'd recommend using [SourceTree](https://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/overview/) rather than using the command line, however.

Comment: I am doing it via the Check Out window. All it has is a textbox and a next button. Can i grab it via this or should I just quit and learn sourcetree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the Check Out first - just go ahead and check out the project repo. (You may already have done this.)

Now you have, on your computer, the *whole repo*, including earlier commits (versions) of the project. In other words, you didn't just check out; you cloned.

Now use Log View to find the commit you think will work.

Now check out that commit. You'll have to use the command line or Source Tree to do that; Xcode's weenie source control support won't help you with it.